# for loops and if statements without {}s?

Tags: php, objective-c

They are pretty popular but I never have the "balls" to use them.

Basically, I never know where they are going to stop. Do they just execute the next line of code?

If I do:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        //this is included in the for loop and the if statement
        function();

        // is this?
        function2();

    // where does it stop?
    function3();
```

What about including an else statement?

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        //this is included in the for loop and the if statement
        function();
    else
        // is this run as part of the for loop? even though theres a semi colon before it?
        function2();
```

If I do this...

```
if((int)1 == (int)1) function1(); function2(); function3(); function4();
```

is all of that code run?

what about this?

```
if((int)1 == (int)1) function();

function2();



function3();
```

Does it just run until the next `;`?

Thanks Tom

Comment: run only one row code until ; , you can try it

Comment: Why not just plug the code you just wrote above and try it?

Comment: An if() construct is not a "loop".

Comment: would you prefer me to change the title for clarity?

Comment: If you wish (and in your code comments), although not so much for clarity as for coordinating the words you use with what they mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An if/else/for/foreach/while/do will only execute the very next statement if it doesn't have {}. That includes:

```
if((int)1 != (int)1) function1(); function2(); function3(); function4();
```

the first function will not run because the if is not met, the others are not included in the if

The general rule is always use {}, it makes the code more clear and readable

Comment: Agreed - I might have to read your code someday, so please don't skip the {} - it just makes the code hard to read when you skip them.

Comment: According to Zend omitting braces is only allowed if an abortion-statement like `return` or `throw` is used.

Comment: Exactly. (+1) For me, I find it helps to realize that `if (conditional) statement` reduces to `statement` in the grammar, and also that `{ statement; /* one or more of those */ }` reduces to `statement` as well.

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant explaination. :) And I do always use {}, but without those looked a little more efficient for my poor over-worked fingers. :p so just out of interest what would `if(condition) statement; statement2; else statement3; statement4;` do?

Comment: @Thomas Clayson: IF THAT COMPILED (which it won't), `statement` would execute conditionally. `statement2` always executes. That said, the `else` is no longer recognizably bound to an `if` statement (because `statement2` is outside the if statement's scope), so you'll get some sort of "else without if" compilation error.

Comment: oh fair enough. :P cool, thanks a lot, I understand much more now. :) thanks for all your help.

Comment: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live" - Martin Golding

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the language.

In many languages, basically most of the C derivatives, an if-statement only executes the next statement or block of statements. (In fact, in most of the underlying grammars, a block of statements DOES reduce to a single statement!) This is true in the following languages (that I know of):

- C
- C++
- PHP
- Java
- C#

In your first code example, only `function()` is bound to the if conditional.

In Perl, the designer decided to force blocks to go after if-statements. For single-statement if's, though, there are statement suffixes. So the following are equivalent:

```
# if-statement preceding block...
if (x == 5)
{
  print "x is 5";
}

# if-statement as a suffix conditional to one statement (line break for readability)
print "x is 5"
  if x == 5;

# Equivalent to the second, because "do BLOCK;" can be used anywhere a
# simple statement can be used
do
{
  print "x is 5";
} if x == 5;
```

Python works a bit more like your initial example would suggest: indentation is everything.

```
if (x == 5):
  print "x is 5"
print "This is always printed"
```

Comment: Just do not forget that PHP also has an alternative syntax for conditionals and looping that does not require curly braces - for instance `if (): endif;`.

Answer (score 1):

These are the equivalents:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        //this is included in the for loop and the if loop
        function();
    }
}
// is this?
function2();

// where does it stop?
function3();
```

....

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        //this is included in the for loop and the if loop
        function();
    }
    else {
        // is this run as part of the for loop? even though theres a semi colon before it?
        function2();
    }
}
```

...

```
if((int)1 == (int)1) {
    function1();
}
function2();
function3();
function4();
```

...

```
if((int)1 == (int)1) {
    function();
}
function2();
function3();
```

...

In summary, anything between {} are treated as a single statement - and vice versa.

Comment: For the second code block you posted: `function2()` is run as part of the `for` (if the conditional fails, of course). This is because `if (condition) statement else statement` can reduce to a single `statement` in the grammar.

Comment: @azure: that is exactly the reason why the braces of the for() statement enclose the entire if...else

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't see them. I'm not used to K&R, isn't that terrible? That said, you'll find that if you removed the braces it would still work as advertised :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use an "inline" if state, you can do it like this:

```
bool greaterthan(int a, int b){
   return a>b ? true:false;
}
```

which essentially means If a>b, return true, otherwise, return false. This can be usedin many other ways too!

Answer (score 0):

The next logical evaluation "block" is executed, which in general means the next "statement" (terminating with a ";") is executed.

Program flow commands are considered a statement for purposes of evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

All the C based languages (PHP is syntactically C based) work in the following way:

```
for (foo1();foo2();foo3())
    operation1();
operation2();
```

Above only operation1() will be executed

```
if (foo())
    operation1();
operation2();
```

Above only operation1() will be executed

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a compound statement (statements enclosed by {}), only the very first line will be included

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
 if(i==5)                // included in loop
     printf("%d\n",i);   // included since if is included. 
 else
     prinf("Not Five"); // Included if is included
```

if statments, if-else statements, for loop, while loop etc are considered as one line

Similarly

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    function1();    // included
function2();         // not included
```

Hope you understood.

Comment: You should either indent all your code lines with four spaces, or highlight your code text and click on the button with 0101 on it. This will present your code in a pre-formatted, syntax-highlighted block, making it far more readable. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that this syntax isn't recommended because it has a tenancy to backfire easily.  Take the following, for example:

```
if (true)
    // not working properly. Exclude it for now
    //    foo()

bar();
```

In such a case, bar() get's executed because it is the next logical statement, even though it is clearly not the intended statement to be run.  This has the potential to cause massive headaches, all from a simple comment and poorly structured 'if'

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the language you're using.  Just learn the language.

Comment: not very helpful, and after all these answers, there was just no point was there?